# Translate content in iFrame

Tags: iframe, translate

Hope someone can help!

I have this booking system within a iFrame - http://designbyaltitude.com/testing/

I need to translate it into Dutch but none of the free translators like google/wordlingo etc don't translate it perfectly.

So is there a way I can find and replace the words within the iframe?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot read (or modify) the DOM within an iframe if it's not on the same domain. This is a violation of the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).